# 2SXC: PersonnaBar overwrites modal dialogs in DNN 9

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

The personnaBar in DNN9 overlays the left half of some of the larger modal dialog boxes.  How can this be corrected?
I have tried editing set.min.css directly by adding "padding-left: 4em" to the ".modal-dialog" class  which works when applied directly with Firebug in Firefox, but does not seem to be read when the page is rendered.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can try adding !important to your css mod.

Answer (score 0):

This was a CSS z-index issue. It's resolved in latest 2sxc 8.9.1 - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases